# Cannot create index for MongoDB replica set: ReplicaSetNoPrimary

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am writing integration testing for my Go program. When I try to initiate my MongoDB (with Docker) running in replica set, it raise error:

```js
server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology:

{
    Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary,
    Servers: [
        {
            Addr: b3ec1125321a:27017,
            Type: Unknown,
            Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup b3ec1125321a on 10.225.109.87:53: no such host
        },
    ]
}
```

So I try to create a minimal runnable code as below with comment:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os/exec"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

// getDockerPath returns the path for docker.
func getDockerPath() (string, error) {
    return exec.LookPath("docker")
}

// getPort returns a useable port. (should use it as soon as you can)
func getPort() (int, error) {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("listen to port 0: %w", err)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    return l.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port, nil
}

// runMongo will run a MongoDB container in docker.
func runMongo(ctx context.Context) error {
    dockerPath, err := getDockerPath()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("get docker path: %w", err)
    }
    mongoPort, err := getPort()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("get mongo port: %w", err)
    }
    mongoURL := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://127.0.0.1:%d", mongoPort)
    fmt.Printf("Starting a mongoDB listening on %s\n\n", mongoURL)

    // Run MongoDB - build command and run.
    args := []string{
        "run", "-d", "-p", fmt.Sprintf("%d:27017", mongoPort),
        "mongo",
        "mongod", "--replSet=rs0",
    }
    startCmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, dockerPath, args...)
    stdout := &bytes.Buffer{}
    startCmd.Stdout = stdout
    if err := startCmd.Run(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("run MongoDB container by docker: %w", err)
    }

    // Get the Docker container name.
    containerName, err := stdout.ReadString('\n')
    for err != nil {
        containerName, err = stdout.ReadString('\n')
    }
    containerName = containerName[:6]

    // **********************************************************************
    // NOTICE: When I remove the code below to initiate the MongoDB's Replica
    // Set. And remove the argument `--replSet rs0`, it works.
    // **********************************************************************
    //
    // Initiate Mongo's Replica Set.
    args = []string{
        "exec", containerName,
        "mongo", "--eval", "rs.initiate();",
    }
    err = errors.New("in loop")
    for err != nil {
        <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
        initCmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, dockerPath, args...)
        fmt.Println(initCmd)
        err = initCmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    // Init MongoDB before use it.
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURL))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot connect to MongoDB: %w", err)
    }
    indexName := "Namespace's name's unique index"
    True := true
    index, err := client.Database("tmp").Collection("namespace").Indexes().CreateOne(ctx, mongo.IndexModel{
        Keys: bson.D{{Key: "name", Value: 1}},
        Options: &options.IndexOptions{
            Name:   &indexName,
            Unique: &True,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("create index for namespace: %w", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(index)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := runMongo(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Fail to run MongoDB: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

When I try to run, it throw an error:

```
$ go run .
Starting a mongoDB listening on mongodb://127.0.0.1:29597

/usr/bin/docker exec b3ec11 mongo --eval rs.initiate();
Fail to run MongoDB: create index for namespace: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: b3ec1125321a:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup b3ec1125321a on 10.225.109.87:53: no such host }, ] }
```

I try to search on Google. But still cannot find a solution.

---

**UPDATE**: I can use mongosh to do it without any error:

```bash
$ mongosh mongodb://127.0.0.1:29597
> use tmp
> ns = db.getCollection("namespace")
> ns.createIndex({name: 1}, {unique: true, name: "Namespace's name's unique index"})
```

And this really worry me a lot - I cannot get why I can use `mongosh` but not the go-driver of MongoDB.

It tells me that now it is `ReplicaSetNoPrimary`. But I try to use `mongosh` to connect it and run `rs.isMaster()` - it tells me that the only running MongoDB node **IS** the master node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to let the MongoDB use the network host but not the bridge, and then it works:

```
--- another.go  2022-08-28 17:14:58.536381918 +0800
+++ main.go     2022-08-28 17:16:06.193467707 +0800
@@ -40,13 +40,13 @@
                return fmt.Errorf("get mongo port: %w", err)
        }
        mongoURL := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://127.0.0.1:%d", mongoPort)
-       fmt.Printf("Starting a mongoDB listening on %s\n\n", mongoURL)
+       fmt.Printf("Starting a mongoDB listening on %s [on host network]\n\n", mongoURL)
 
        // Run MongoDB - build command and run.
        args := []string{
-               "run", "-d", "-p", fmt.Sprintf("%d:27017", mongoPort),
+               "run", "-d", "--net=host",
                "mongo",
-               "mongod", "--replSet=rs0",
+               "mongod", "--replSet=rs0", fmt.Sprintf("--port=%d", mongoPort),
        }
        startCmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, dockerPath, args...)
        stdout := &bytes.Buffer{}
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@
        // Initiate Mongo's Replica Set.
        args = []string{
                "exec", containerName,
-               "mongo", "--eval", "rs.initiate();",
+               "mongo", "--eval", "rs.initiate();", mongoURL,
        }
        err = errors.New("in loop")
        for err != nil {
```

But I still do not know why I cannot let it work in bridge network. [Waiting for another answer still...]